# Django: Multiple formsets within a form

Tags: django, formset

I am working on some Django forms for which the code base is inherited from someone else, which is fine, but adds to the confusion.

I am trying to add a second formset to a form. When the second formset is added, both formsets appear on the page, but seem to contain no forms on the backend. Here is an example of my code (I've added more than is probably recommended, but I didn't want to miss something important):

view.py:

```
class Thing(StaffRequiredMixin, DetailView):
model = models.Thing

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

    ...

    context = self.get_context_data(**kwargs)

    dispatch = {
        "thing_form": self.handle_thing_form,
        ...
    }

    return dispatch[self.request.POST.get("form_name")](context)

...

def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):

    context = super(Thing, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
    thing = self.model.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs["pk"])
    context["thing"] = thing

    to_handle = self.request.POST.get("form_name")

    if to_handle == "thing_form":
        context["thing_form"] = forms.Thing(
                   self.request.POST, 
                   instance=thing)

        context["formset1"] = forms.FormSet1(
                   self.request.POST,
                   queryset=models.Model1.objects.filter(thing=self.object),
                   prefix="thing1")

        context["formset2"] = forms.FormSet2(
                   self.request.POST, 
                   queryset=models.Model2.objects.filter(thing=self.object),
                   prefix="thing2")
    else:
        context["thing_form"] = forms.Thing(
                   instance=thing, 
                   user=self.request.user)

        context["formset1"] = forms.FormSet1(
                   queryset=models.Model1.objects.filter(thing=self.object),
                   prefix="stuff1")

        context["formset2"] = forms.FormSet2(
                   queryset=models.Model2.objects.filter(thing=self.object),
                   prefix="stuff2")

    # Other to_handle stuff
    ...

    return context

def handle_thing_form(self, context):

    form = context['thing_form']
    formset1 = context['formset1']
    formset2 = context['formset2']

    if form.is_valid() and formset1.is_valid() and formset2.is_valid():

        # Do some form logic
        ...

        form.save()

        # Formset stuff:
        # here, the formsets contain no forms
        changed_1 = [f for f in formset1 if f.has_changed()]
        changed_2 = [f for f in formset2 if f.has_changed()]

        for a_form in changed_1:

            #Do some formset logic
            ...

            a_form.save()

        for a_form in changed_2:
            #similar to 1

        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_next_url())

    return self.render_to_response(context)
```

forms.py:

```
class Form1(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = models.Model1
        fields = ("field1", "field2", ...)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        super(Form1, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # Some readonly widget stuff etc
        ...


class Form2(ModelForm):

    #Same idea as Form1
    ...


FormSet1 = modelformset_factory(models.Model1, form=Form1, extra=0)
FormSet2 = modelformset_factory(models.Model2, form=Form2, extra=0)
```

template:

```
<form id="thing-form" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="form_name" value="thing_form" />

    {% for field in thing_form.visible_fields %}

        {{ field }}
        ...

    {% endfor %}


    <a id="add-form1">Add</a>

    {{formset1.management_form}}
    <div id="formset1-div">

        {% for form in formset1.forms %}

            {{form.id}}
            {% for field in form.visible_fields %}

                <div class="controls">
                    {{field}}
                </div>

            {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
    </div>

    <div id="empty-form1>

        {% for field in formset1.empty_form.visible_fields %}
            <div class="controls">
                {{field}}
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>

    {{formset2.management_form}}
    <div id="formset2-div">

        {# same idea as above #}
        ...

    </div>

    <button type="submit">Update</button>
</form>
```

javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#add-form1').click(function() {
        $('#formset1-div').prepend($('#empty_form1').html().replace(/__prefix__/g, 'thing1'));
        $('#id_form-TOTAL_FORMS').val(parseInt('thing1') + 1);
    });

    if ($("#formset1-div input").length === 0){
        $("#add-form1").trigger("click");
    }

    // Similar button stuff for formset2
    ...

})
```

Anyways, I've added a lot here, but I did so because I'm not sure where I went wrong, or even if what I'm trying to do is possible.

Answer (score 2):

WOW I am so dumb. The javascript portion should be something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#add-form1').click(function() {
        var thing1_index = $('#id_thing1-TOTAL_FORMS').val();
        $('#formset1-div').prepend($('#empty_form1').html().replace(/__prefix__/g, thing1_index));
        $('#id_thing1-TOTAL_FORMS').val(parseInt(thing1_index) + 1);
    });

    if ($("#formset1-div input").length === 0){
        $("#add-form1").trigger("click");
    }

    // Similar button stuff for formset2
    ...

})
```

Not sure how I missed the obvious `parseInt('thing1')` makes no sense.

Anyways, it works now. Maybe someone looking at multiple formsets will find something in here useful `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: No, you're not dumb, it's that Django's templating doesn't lend itself well to complex web UIs. Like you, I found the templates soon became too fragile to maintain. Multiple nested formsets eventually drove me to AngularJS, using Django and the Django REST Framework as the backend. I've found the combo works quite well. Just my 2¢, glad you figured it out.